# Ignite jquery plugin on hover

Tags: jquery, plugins, hover, marquee

There is one thing, what I should make for client web page. All done, except plugin is not working properly. Anyways, there comes a little description.

First of all, I'm using Wordpress, but probably this doesn't make any changes.
Secondly, I have to make latest post list, which displays post title, and excerpt text of that post. But client wanted also that excerpt to marquee. And more - client wanted to show only first post excerpt marquee by default, others - on hover.
I started of to look for suitable jquery plugin, and [this](http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm) seemed best. Then I wrote php code:

http://pastebin.com/LWmaFvqz

Everything works great. But problem is, that every "<li><? the_excerpt()?></li>" is marquee'ing around.

Then I added class marquee_hide, and tried to remove it on hover like this:

http://pastebin.com/ZC4QtTbP

There is a problem, which, I hope, somebody will help to solve. And problem is that, when I hover that title, I get some content, but plugin is not working. But I tested, if I hover this while page is loading, that marquee plugin is working.
So, I tought, there might be some kind of function, almost like $(document).ready(), but just which starts working not, when page is loaded, but then, when hover is triggered.

I hope, I described my problem clear, so You could help me :)

PS - Done some changes in css, and got better result. This plugin asks to be visible on page load. This display: none messed all evening. I just thought to use height: 0 instead of display: none, so this li is visible for jquery, but not for our eyes. And it quite much works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually just create a method/function that triggers the plugin again pretty simple by just adding your triggers to a method and then with jquery trigger the created method.

Comment: And how this works? :)
I think, I forgot to mention, that I am pretty much beginner at jQuery and Javascript at all.